# pygame only displays grey window on screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to use pygame to show a game scene, but it seems to have stopped working for me: it displays nothing more than a grey box in any screen I create until pygame shuts down, then what should be on the screen flashes briefly before it exits. For instance, the minimal code below displays a grey screen for 5 seconds, then flashes black quickly and quits:

```
import pygame as pg
import time
pg.init()
sc = pg.display.set_mode((600,600))
sc.fill((0,0,0))
pg.display.flip()
time.sleep(5)
```

This seems to be an issue with the screen display and not pygame itself, since I can make surfaces and save them to image files with pg.image.save(), and they look fine there.

This is the first time I've tried using pygame to display on the screen since I upgraded to OSX 10.12. This is using Python 2.7, and pygame 1.9.3 (downloaded from pip, but also an issue with the dev 1.9.4 version from bitbucket). All of the sdl dependencies are at the latest version (according to homebrew).

However, I'm now lost for how to do more troubleshooting, since I don't know enough about the innards of how pygame communicates with the display. Is there anything else I can do to help find the root of this problem and correct it?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't how pygame works. You can't simply use time.sleep() to display things, because pygame is specifically designed to have a main loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a game loop that continually does the following:

- calls pygame.display.flip() -- this will update the screen with new changes
- calls pygame.event.get() -- this is the most important because otherwise, the event queue will not get flushed and the OS will assume your program is being unresponsive. You can't have things like `sleep(5)` in PyGame.

Comment: Thank you! It seems it was the event.get() call that was the issue. I guess I've always used it in the past and didn't know that it was a requirement. But you don't need the loop -- the code works just fine if I add pg.event.get() right after pg.display.flip()

Comment: It'll display, yes. But you still need the loop. The app is unresponsive when it's not actively and continually pumping the event queue. For example, trying closing or moving the window during those 5 seconds.